# Sample without replacement, or duplicates, in R

Tags: r, permutation, random

I have a long list, which contains quite a few duplicates, say for example 100,000 values, 20% of which are duplicates.  I want to randomly sample from this list, placing all values into groups, say 400 of them.  However, I don't want any of the subsequent groups to contain duplicate values within them - i.e. I want all 250 members of each group to be unique.

I've tried using various permutation methods from vegan, picante, EcoSimR, but they don't do quite what I want, or seem to struggle with the large amount of data.

I wondered if there was just some way of using the sample function that I can't figure out?  Any help or alternative suggestions would be much appreciated...

Comment: Do you need the samples to be unique across groups (i.e. I sample 250 records, then I sample 250 more records, and so on - but for all the groups across all the samples a given record appears only once)?

Comment: The `unique` function springs to mind...

Comment: Even though you want each value to appear only once, do you want the probability of being sampled to be proportional to the number of times it appears in your original data? If so, you can create a vector of just the unique values, but use the `prob` argument of the `sample` function to set sampling probabilities that are proportional to the number of times each value appears in your original list.

Comment: No, I'm happy for samples to duplicate between groups, just not within a group.

Comment: Ideally, I want all 100,000 values to be defined to a group at the same time (400 groups of 125).  So, each group will have 125 unique samples, but samples can be repeated between groups.

Comment: In response to eipi10, yes I suppose I do want it proportional.  If all samples are assigned to a group at the same time, then hopefully this would happen itself.  Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted by [nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176923/nico) you probably just need to use the `unique` function. A very simple sampling program is below which ensures that there won't be duplication across the groups (which isn't totally sensible, because you could just create one big sample instead...)

```
# Getting some random values to use here
set.seed(seed = 14412)
thevalues <- sample(x = 1:100,size = 1000,replace = TRUE)

# Obtaining the unique vector of those values
thevalues.unique <- unique(thevalues)

# Create a sample without replacement (i.e. take the ball out and don't put it back in)
sample1 <- sample(x = thevalues.unique,size = 10,replace = FALSE)

# Remove the sampled items from the vector of values
thevalues.unique <- thevalues.unique[!(thevalues.unique %in% sample1)]

# Another sample, and another removal
sample2 <- sample(x = thevalues.unique,size = 10,replace = FALSE)
thevalues.unique <- thevalues.unique[!(thevalues.unique %in% sample2)]
```

To do what [eipi10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/496488/eipi10) mentioned and get a weighted distribution, you just need to get the frequency of the distribution first. A way of doing this:

```
set.seed(seed = 14412)
thevalues <- sample(x = 1:100,size = 1000,replace = TRUE,prob = c(rep(0.01,100)))

thevalues.unique <- unique(thevalues)
thevalues.unique <- thevalues.unique[order(thevalues.unique)]
thevalues.probs <- table(thevalues)/length(thevalues)
sample1 <- sample(x = thevalues.unique,
                  size = 10,
                  replace = FALSE,
                  prob = thevalues.probs)
```

Comment: And then `replicate` on that last command for 400 such samples.

Comment: Thanks TARehman, that's very helpful.  I may end up doing exactly like this.  However, I was really hoping to assign all groups at once.  And more importantly, this seems to stop samples being repeated across groups, as well as within them.  I actually want all samples allocated to a group, so am happy to have duplicates between groups.  Sorry this wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: Also, what is the order() function in the second bit of code doing?  Is it needed? Thanks

Comment: I added that so that `thevalues.unique` would be sorted in the same order as the results in `table(thevalues)`, so that the vector of derived frequencies used for `prob` would be right. I don't know if it was needed but it seemed prudent. As to sampling simultaneously, if you aren't worried about replication `lapply()` and `sample()` would probably work. If you want I'll edit in a way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I think I've managed it.  Still don't quite get order() though - when I use it, it seems to produce a completely unrelated vector of numbers, rather than just sorting them.  Maybe sort() will work instead

Comment: Oh...you are absolutely right. I made a mistake and will edit the answer. I should have put order() inside the vector to actually order it.

Comment: To clarify, order returns the indices of the vector in their proper order (i.e. B,A,D,C,E would be 2,1,4,3,5). To get the vector in the right order, you need to use the returned vector of indices to select the elements from the vector in the right order.